# Make C# applications look nice

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have been designing many applications for my company lately where "fancy" interfaces have not been needed, and where the "basic" controls have been good enough in terms of looks.

However, I have just been handed a project where the "typical" VS(Visual Studio 2010) look is not going to cut it.  Is there some where that I can get "fancy"er looking controls for VS so that it does not look like a cheap build, or a basic windows program?

Comment: winform? wpf? use the later if you want a clean app.

Comment: you could try using Expression Blend http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx

Comment: There are a number of libraries that provide fancy UI's. Devexpress (http://www.devexpress.com) and Telerik (http://www.telerik.com) spring to mind.

Comment: Windows forms, but WPF looks like the way to go.

Comment: @reid once you taste WPF (+ MVVM) you will never want to back to winforms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go and learn [**Windows Presentation Foundation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation). It utilizes DirectX and provides developers with a compact model for building rich user experiences for Windows-based systems. You can start [on this tutorial site](http://www.wpftutorial.net/) to learn about what WPF is and what you can do with that framework.

Also check out these components to see the power of WPF:

- [DevExpress DXperience](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/WhatsNew2012v1/wpf.xml)
- [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx)
- [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWPF/)
- [Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/wpf)

Comment: I have used Devexpress Mvc and it have been causing more issues for our team then help. It can help you to quickly develop some small application throw it to a customer and forget about it. Devexress is definitely a bad choice for long running elaborate applications. Check this review: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/410847/Review-of-DevExpress-WinForms-Controls?msg=4305435#xx4305435xx

Comment: @DmytroLaptin, did you contact the vendor? It is one of the leading vendors in the market. I can't believe this!

Comment: To me, VS supplied WPF controls are ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the options:

1. Move to WPF.
2. [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/), [Devexpress](http://devexpress.com/), [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/) etc offer richer library, but could leave a hole in your pocket.
3. Bare minimum, you could just [How can you make a .net windows forms project look fresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703/how-can-you-make-a-net-windows-forms-project-look-fresh)

Comment: If you are using 3rd party tools, WPF controls don't offer much more than what Winforms tool kits offer. Most vendors offer comparable controls. The pain in learning WPF is hard to justify!